# Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, dynatrace

I am following Install OneAgent on Kubernetes official instructions while doing this I am getting the error mentioned in the title. when I add --name after helm install I am getting

```
Error: apiVersion 'v2' is not valid. The value must be "v1"
```

helm instructions:

```
helm install dynatrace-oneagent-operator \
dynatrace/dynatrace-oneagent-operator -n\
dynatrace --values values.yaml
```

Comment: what is your helm version? `helm version`

Comment: Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.1", GitCommit:"bbdfe5e7803a12bbdf97e94cd847859890cf4050", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.1", GitCommit:"bbdfe5e7803a12bbdf97e94cd847859890cf4050", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Comment: since you are using helm2, you should use apiVersion as v1 in Chart.yaml.  
apiVersion v2 is for helm3.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're using [this helm chart](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/dynatrace/dynatrace-oneagent-operator) it's stated in its description that it requires **helm 3**:

> The Dynatrace OneAgent Operator Helm Chart which supports the rollout
> and lifecycle of Dynatrace OneAgent in Kubernetes and OpenShift
> clusters.
>
> This Helm Chart requires Helm 3.

and you use **Helm 2**:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.1", GitCommit:"bbdfe5e7803a12bbdf97e94cd847859890cf4050", GitTreeState:"clean"} Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.1", GitCommit:"bbdfe5e7803a12bbdf97e94cd847859890cf4050", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

As to your error message:

```
Error: apiVersion 'v2' is not valid. The value must be "v1"
```

it can be expected on **helm 2** when running a chart that requires **helm 3** as the `apiVersion` has been incremented from `v1` to `v2` only in **helm 3**. In fact this is one of the major differences between two releases of **helm**. You can read more about it [here](https://dev.to/ridaehamdani/some-changes-between-helm-v2-and-helm-v3-that-you-should-know-32ga):

> 3. Chart apiVersion:
>
> Helm decides to increment the chart API version to v2 in Helm3:
>
> ```
> # Chart.yaml
> -apiVersion: v1 # Helm2
> +apiVersion: v2 # Helm3
> ...
> ```

You can install **Helm 3** easily by following [this official guide](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/).

Note that apart from using **helm** chart, you can also deploy **OneAgent Operator** on **Kubernetes** with `kubectl` and as you can read in the [official dynatrace docs](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/technology-support/cloud-platforms/kubernetes/deploy-oneagent-k8/) this is actually the recommended way of installation:

> We recommend installing OneAgent Operator on Kubernetes with kubectl.
> If you prefer Helm, you can use the OneAgent Helm chart as a basic
> alternative.

Answer (score 1):

These errors are resolved for me!
#This command needs 1 argument: chart name
#apiVersion 'v2' is not valid. The value must be "v1"
#release seq-charts failed: namespaces "seq" is forbidden: User
"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API
group "" in the namespace "seq"

I started using local PowerShell for Azure Kubernetes.
These errors started when I made some changes to the Windows environment, but mine might work for you too.

```
PS C:\Users\{User}> Connect-AzAccount
PS C:\Users\{User}> Set-AzContext 'Subscription Name or ID'
PS C:\Users\{User}> az configure --defaults group=AKS
PS C:\Users\{User}> kubectl create namespace seq
PS C:\Users\{User}> kubectl create namespace prometheus-log
PS C:\Users\{User}> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco upgrade chocolatey
PS C:\Users\{User}> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install kubernetes-helm
```

After that.

```
 PS C:\Users\{User}> helm install --name prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --namespace prometheus-log 
Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name
```

After that, I tried this.

```
PS C:\Users\{User}> C:\Users\vahem\.azure-helm\helm install --name prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --namespace prometheus-log 
Error: apiVersion 'v2' is not valid. The value must be "v1"
```

After that, I tried this.

```
PS C:\Users\{User}> helm install --name seq-charts --namespace seq --set persistence.existingClaim=seq-pvc stable/seq
Error: release seq-charts failed: namespaces "seq" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "seq"
```

After much trial and error, I discovered that there are two different versions of 'helm' on the system.
C:\Users{User}.azure-helm => V2.x.x
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-helm\tools\windows-amd64\helm =>V3.x.x

Finally I tried this and it worked great. Using 'helm v3.x.x' and no parameter name '--name'

```
PS C:\Users\{User}> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-helm\tools\windows-amd64\helm repo update
PS C:\Users\{User}> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-helm\tools\windows-amd64\helm install seq-charts --namespace seq --set persistence.existingClaim=seq-pvc stable/seq
PS C:\Users\{User}> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-helm\tools\windows-amd64\helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --namespace prometheus-log --set persistence.existingClaim=prometheus-pvc
```

It Worket Great For Me!

Answer (score -1):

Please upgrade your helm version to 3. unless you are using a tillerless version of the helm2.